# Javascript - odd bug or functionality for select tags

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have code that verifies form inputs before submit. In there is a snippet that doesnt work very well:

```
if(elem[i].tagName == 'SELECT'){
    alert('1' + elem[i].name);

    if (elem[i].selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert('2' + elem[i].name);
        elem[i].style.backgroundColor = window.errorColor;
        pass = false;
    } //SELECT SHOULD NOT BE OPTION 0
}
```

What is happening is the first alert will fire, while the second alert is skipped, as well as the backgroundColor change, but pass is still being set to false. If i remove the second alert, the backgroundColor will change.

Inside of the if statement, no alerts will fire that use information from the select tag. Any other alerts around the if will show fine, but when it comes time for an alert within the if and using data from the select tag, the screen will flash and it appears an alert pops up but instantly goes away.

This is in firefox btw, and console shows no errors. Likewise this is occurring no matter what selectedIndex is.

Comment: This sounds like something people might want to play with.  Can you make us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?  Also, since the alert seems to be debug statements, can you use `console.log` and see if you get different behavior?  It may just be a weird interaction between `alert` and a selection occurring.

Comment: I bet there is some asynchronicity surrounding this snippet and that's causing code to happen in an order you do not expect.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I tried to create a fiddle, but the super simplified verison i created is working fine :P

Comment: @Category6 Yea now that i made a simply version in fiddle there is something else whacky about it. I have a rather large initialization page, plus a lot of other code and something is just causing this buggy bit. (which I also have quite a bit of jquery attached to the same leements)

Comment: Ok it was something that Im not even positive of the functionality. But I wasnt using brackets for the if statements. I thought that a braceless if would execute everything before a line break. once I added braces to all the if's everything is working fine.

Comment: Javascript ignores white space in general. (That's how minification works!) As you said, the braces are essential. Otherwise, it assumes only the first statement after the if is part of the if.

Comment: @MagicLasso At some point, you should write up and accept your own answer, so the question will be marked as answered and others will more likely learn from your experience.